# Accessing Google APIs through a proxy with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, windows-services

I've created an application using c# that connected to Google api through a proxy. I used the method that you see in the link below.
https://kzhendev.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/accessing-google-apis-through-a-proxy-with-net/

But my program works perfectly in console and application mode, but when I implement it with a Windows service, the TokenResponse-user file is not updated, that is, when access_token expired, it does not update the content (Refresh Token) while it is in the application and the console correctly.

I guess the bug is in the system mode. That is, the service runs from the system user, but the application runs through the local user.

Please guide me about this.
If there is an example source code available, it will be useful to me.
thank you

Comment: Windows services run under some weird user.  Make sure that user has access to write to the file in the location in question.    When you change it you may want to reboot before restarting the service.   To test it set the service to run under your own personal user make sure it works then.

Comment: When it's connected to the Internet, it's not going to be a problem and it's done right.

Comment: Even Main Program is done correctly, but I want to do it periodically When the service is running.

Comment: i'm sure access to write to the file. so test service to run under personal user but Did not work properly.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve i will have a look